# sudo: /usr/bin/systemctl vs /bin/systemctl

Tags: sudo

Up to now, we have two lines in our sudoers file, since `systemctl` is sometimes in `/usr/bin` and sometimes in `/bin` (depending on the linux distro):

```
    foo ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/systemctl restart foo.service
    foo ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl restart foo.service
```

Is there a feasible way to write this in one line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is enough to write this sudo line:

```
foo ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl restart foo.service
```

According to the systemd developers the correct location is `/usr/bin/systemctl`, but default Debian/Ubuntu does not follow this "usr-merge".

Luckily, distros which have done the usr-merge provide symlinks.

This means `/bin/systemctl` works on all distros.

Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1164035/why-bin-systemctl

Comment: @anx I am very sorry. Maybe I have misunderstood something. Does the default Debian/Ubuntu image use usr-merge?

Comment: Don't know but don't think so. But `debootstap` switched its default for recent releases, so I expect enough people to use Ubuntu in a merged layout to invalidate any assumption based on merely the distribution.

Comment: @anx Debian 10 (buster) has finally done the /usr move, but Ubuntu LTS has not yet, nor have previous Debian releases.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible to specify multiple commands in the sudoers file by separating them with commas.  For your example with systemctl, the line would be

```
foo ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/systemctl restart foo.service, /bin/systemctl restart foo.service
```